# Autohotkey: Restart a "screensaver" script/part of a script (Starting VLC)

Tags: automation, autohotkey, idle-timer

I wanted to create a "VLC-screensaver" script:

When the user/system is idle for a certain time VLC should start and play a video from a specified folder. I can start the script and VLC is being executed by it after the set time. Now I exit it with "Esc" and VLC closes.

After I closed it the AHK-tray is visible but VLC/the script is not starting again after the set time...

Where is the mistake? Thank you in advance!

```html
#Persistent

SetTimer, Check, 1000
return

Check:
If (A_TimeIdle>=10000)
{
 run C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe --repeat --fullscreen "D:\video"
 SetTimer, Check, Off
}
return

#IfWinActive ahk_exe vlc.exe
Escape::Send !{F4}
#IfWinActive
return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it by myself:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe vlc.exe
Escape::
    Send !{F4}
    Reload
#IfWinActive
Return
```

Forgot that you can assign more than one action/paramter/value to one
key...